# Detect when exe is started vb.net

Tags: vb.net, process

Dose anybody know how I can make my VB.net application wait until a process is detected as running?

I can find example of how to detect once an exe has finished running but none that detect when an exe is started?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to wait for certain WMI events to occur.  You need to give it a query type and condition to have it watch for the next creation of your process, then get it to do something when that occurs.

For example, if you want :

```
Dim watcher As ManagementEventWatcher

Public Sub Main()
    Dim monitoredProcess = "Notepad.exe"
    Dim query As WqlEventQuery = New WqlEventQuery("__InstanceCreationEvent", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), "TargetInstance isa ""Win32_Process"" And TargetInstance.Name = """ & monitoredProcess & """")

    watcher = New ManagementEventWatcher()
    watcher.Query = query

    'This starts watching asynchronously, triggering EventArrived events every time a new event comes in.
    'You can do synchronous watching via the WaitForNextEvent() method
    watcher.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub Watcher_EventArrived(sender As Object, e As EventArrivedEventArgs) Handles watcher.EventArrived
    'Do stuff with the startup event
End Sub
```

Eventually you'll need to stop the watcher, which is you can do by closing the app, or calling `watcher.Stop()`.  This has been written as brain compiler, so if there's any issues let me know.

Comment: I think you'll have to provide an interval: `Dim query As WqlEventQuery = New WqlEventQuery("__InstanceCreationEvent", New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1),"TargetInstance isa ""Win32_Process"" And TargetInstance.Name = """ & monitoredProcess & """")`

Comment: @DominicKexel thanks, I already mentioned the `WaitForNextEvent()` in my code, in the comment just above `watcher.Start()`.  And the interval isn't required.  [The constructor I used in my example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee2ayw2h.aspx) is also valid.  The `TimeSpan` you've specified there really only means that it won't accept events more than one second old.

Comment: Sorry, missed your comment. However, if you don't provide an interval, you'll get a COM-Exception `0x80042002 WBEMESS_E_REGISTRATION_TOO_PRECISE: A WITHIN clause was not used in this query.`; at least I run into this exception on my Win7 machine.

Comment: Okay, I don't get that error, but it doesn't hurt to have the interval there, so I'll update the example.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply wait and check every once in a while whether the process exists. Use `Thread.Sleep` to avoid busy waiting.

However, this has the possibility that you miss the process if it starts and exists during your wait time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below condition

return Process.GetProcesses().Any(Function(p) p.Name.Contains(myProcessName))

Answer (score 0):

```
   Dim p() As Process

 Private Sub CheckIfRunning()
        p = Process.GetProcessesByName("processName")
        If p.Count > 0 Then
            ' Process is running
        Else
            ' Process is not running
        End If
    End Sub
```

OR SIMPLY

> `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("processName")`