# which event is triggered when a word file opens?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm using infinite loop to know when a word file is open.

Is there any other way to avoid infinite loop, like trigger for something?

```vb
Do While True
  CheckIfRunning(NewStatues, OldStatues)
  Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
Loop
```

Comment: What does CheckIfRunning do?  Could you try something like this, using ManagementEventWatcher? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757391/detect-when-exe-is-started-vb-net  (you may have to add System.Management as a reference, it wasn't added by default for me)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect when exe is started vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757391/detect-when-exe-is-started-vb-net)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FileSystemWatcher class.
It can be used to watch & report changes to files and directories.

> Opening a file, in this case, generates a change in the directory
>   files structure because a temporary file is created, thus causing
>   the FileSystemWatcher to report the event.
>  Depending on which events
>   have been subscribed, more than one event may be raised.

`FileSystemEventArgs` gives information about the event:

➜ .ChangeType      Defines what changed (a file has been renamed, opened, deleted...)
  ➜ .Name                       Name of the File or Directory affected
  ➜ .FullPath               Fully qualified name of the file or directory

```
Private WithEvents fsw As System.IO.FileSystemWatcher

Private Sub SetupFileSystemWatcher()
    fsw = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()
    fsw.Filter = "*.docx"
    fsw.Path = "SomePathToWatch"

    'Set at least a filter to NotifyFilters.LastAccess, so that when a
    'file is opened (saved, created, deleted, renamed), you are notified
    fsw.NotifyFilter = (System.IO.NotifyFilters.LastAccess Or _
                        System.IO.NotifyFilters.LastWrite Or _
                        System.IO.NotifyFilters.FileName Or _
                        System.IO.NotifyFilters.DirectoryName)

    'Set the handler to the events you want to receive
    AddHandler fsw.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
    AddHandler fsw.Created, AddressOf OnChanged
    AddHandler fsw.Deleted, AddressOf OnChanged
    AddHandler fsw.Renamed, AddressOf OnRenamed
    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub

'Setup the delegates to receive the events raised by the FileWatcher
Private Shared Sub OnChanged(sender As Object, e As System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
    Console.Write("A file has been Opened, Saved, Created or Deleted")
End Sub

Private Shared Sub OnRenamed(sender As Object, e As System.IO.RenamedEventArgs)
    Console.Write("A file has been Renamed")
End Sub
```